# add new row with button click using asp.net vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add new row to table ,first and second row add normally but while third row added I get this error:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values
>   in this line of code

```
Table1.Rows.Add(session_table.Rows(i))
```

I trace the row count it was 3 in first loop after add row the row count became 2. I don't understand why the rowcount decreased?

My code is as below

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim R As New TableRow
    Dim C(4) As TableCell
    C(0) = New TableCell
    C(1) = New TableCell
    C(2) = New TableCell
    C(3) = New TableCell
    C(4) = New TableCell
    C(0).Text = martyr_name.Text
    C(1).Text = link.Text
    C(2).Text = martyr_type.Text
    C(3).Text = dec_no.Text
    C(4).Text = dec_date.Text
    R.Cells.AddRange(C)
    Table1.Rows.Add(R)

    If Session("Table") Is Nothing Then
        Session.Add("table", Table1)
    Else
        Session("table") = Table1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Session("table") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim session_table As New Table
        session_table = Session("table")
        For i = 1 To session_table.Rows.Count - 1
            Table1.Rows.Add(session_table.Rows(i))
        Next

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: zero based index. You need to loop from position zero rather than one which is why you are experiencing a `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

If you do not care about the order in which rows are added, you can always use a `ForEach` loop which makes dealing with indices less of a concern.

```
Private Sub form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Session("table") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim session_table As New Table
        session_table = Session("table")
        For i = 0 To session_table.Rows.Count - 1
            Table1.Rows.Add(session_table.Rows(i))
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```